# c pointers and arrays, copying contents into another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know this is probably a basic question, but i've never fully grasped the whole pointers concept in C.

My question is, say i have an int array and I pass that into a function like 
`

```
int main(){
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);

    // add values to a
    p(a);
}

void p(int *a){
   int *b = malloc(sizeof(int*)*4)
   b = a;
   // change values in b

   //print a b
}`
```

What is the correct way to do this  so that whatever changes I make to b do not affect the values in a?

Comment: Tell me about it, it took 4.2 hours of asking random suits outside of CSC just to get the URL for this place! I guess there's always Bing, but, no...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your 'p' method, you're assigning pointer b to be pointer a, or, in otherwords, you're making b point to what a points to. Any changes to b will cause changes to a since they both wind up pointing to the same block of memory.

Use memcpy to copy blocks of memory. It would look something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void p(int *a){
   int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
   memcpy(b, a, sizeof(int)*4);

    //make changes to b.
   b[0] = 6;
   b[1] = 7;
   b[2] = 8;
   b[3] = 9;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);

    // add values to a
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 3;
    a[3] = 4;

    p(a);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assigning the pointer means `b` is pointing to the same chunk of memory as `a` and the memory you just allocated "for `b`" has leaked. It's allocated but you can't free it any more.

To copy the array you need to well, copy it.

Easy way is lookup the various `memcpy` methods, or just do it the longer way

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    b[i] = a[i];
}
```

You need to know about "shallow copy" and "deep copy" - since you have an array of `int*`, what I put above is a shallow copy. If you need to copy the contents that each `int*` points to, you'll need something more complex again.

Comment: Great point on leakage! I think it's pointless to point a pointer to an array pointer. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing `a` and `b` to two different blocks of memory and then assigning `b` to the block pointed to by `a`, causing a memory leak.

And since you are not returning anything from your function `p()`, you can allocate `b` on stack (I wonder what you are doing with it).

If your intention is to copy the data pointed to by these pointers, you can use `memcpy` or copy element by element as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support array assignment! You must copy data manually.

- Use [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)
- Use [`memmove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) if a and b (could) overlap
- Use `for` or `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

```
void p(int *a){
   int *b = malloc(sizeof(int*)*4)
   int size=4;
   while(size>=0){
     b[size--]=a[size--];
   }
   // change values in b

   //print a b
}
```

This should work!

Comment: @John3136 It is the address that can be NULL not the value itself

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted... But that makes it even worse: how will `a` ever be NULL when all you do is increment it! Infinite loop! I see you've edited so my first comment is true again.

Comment: @John3136 there is limited memory allocated to a. So if a is incremented, it will get pass the allocated memory eventually

Comment: @Manual Correct. That doesn't mean the value becomes 0, it means you are doing an "uninitialized memory read" (aka UMR). If you are lucky you'll read a 0 and stop the loop before you try to read something you are not allowed to and crash. Most likely scenario is either a crash or an infinite loop. Your basic assumption that there is a 0 in the last place of the array is just a convention for `char[]` when used as strings. It is not a enforced for any array types.